# Changing the color and thickness of smooth histograms of two sets curves on the same graph

Tags: plotting, color, dataset, histograms

I have a code (shown below) where I generate two different sets of data[image] and plot the two sets as a smooth histogram on the same graph. The code works pretty well.

What I'm having an issue with is changing the color and thickness of the two sets of data separately.

As shown in the code, I used Plotstyle->{{Red}, {Gray}}, but what that does is, it divides half the curves into Red and half into Gray. It works fine if both sets of data have the same number of curves, but not so much when there is a big difference.

What can I do here?

```
k = 0.6;
n1 = 10;
n2 = 10;
k1 = 0.4;
n3 = 3;
n4 = 3;
data1 = Table[
   Table[If[RandomReal[] > k, RandomChoice[{100, 90}], 
     RandomChoice[{80, 70, 60, 50, 40}]], n1], n2];
data2 = Table[
   Table[If[RandomReal[] > k1, RandomChoice[{100, 90}], 
     RandomChoice[{40, 30, 20, 10, 0}]], n3], n4];

SmoothHistogram[{data1, data2}, PlotStyle -> {{Red}, {Gray}}, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

Thanks,
Sid

Comment: Do you mean: `SmoothHistogram[Join[data1, data2], PlotStyle -> 
  Join[Table[Red, Length[data1]], Table[Gray, Length[data2]]], ImageSize -> Large]`